# Install php with 'grep -i 'DocumentRoot' httpd.conf'

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I'm installing php on my mac and following these instructions : [Installing Apache, Php, Mysql on Mac OSX Yosemite.](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/)

I'm stopping at this block :

> The default DocumentRoot for Mac OS X Yosemite is /Library/WebServer/Documents. You can verify this from your Apache configuration.

```
grep DocumentRoot httpd.conf
```

> Now create the phpinfo() page in your DocumentRoot:
>
> echo ' /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php
>   Verify PHP by accessing http://localhost/phpinfo.php

But what I got is below : 
[image]

The message 'grep : httpd.conf : No such file or directory' is blocking me from progressing now.

Are there any php specialists out there who can help me?
I'm just following the instructions..

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but assuming that the config files are in `/etc/apache2` you might try `grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `grep -i Documentroot /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Grep is used to search for text inside other files. You are currently executing grep in your own `Documents` folder. Apache's config is not located there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to the directory where you have httpd.conf then try using grep. 
Or simply try this command -> find / -iname httpd.conf. Copy the location, grep -i DocumentRoot (location). **Location of file without parenthesis.**